# Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 and FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-studio, beta

I am trying out the new Android Studio Preview 1 for 2.2, and as soon as I switch I have a compile error that it can't find FloatingActionButton

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
```

Anyone else have this?  I don't see that it's deprecated or removed. And if I run the exact same project in 2.1 with the exact same libraries configured, it compiles and runs.

Comment: It's definitely not deprecated. I have a project with `FloatingActionButton`, which compiles on Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 and runs on a device just fine. But I have it only in XML, I reference it in code just as `View`, because all I care about is `setOnClickListener()`. And as you say it works just fine in 2.1. Probably a bug in 2.2 which you should raise on their bug tracker: http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Comment: The answer from Victor was right, interesting that my gradle file didn't require it in 2.1, but does now in 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your build.gradle file, add this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

Comment: That did it.  I'll accept as soon as SO lets me.  Thanks for the quick response!